# jQuery create a with href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, href

I just faced a very serious issue with jQuery. I wanted to create an element using jQ. Like the regular way I tried: `jQuery('<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>');`

But this does **not** work. So I tried several different element types and attributes. It turned out that I am not able to create elements with HTML containing `href=""`.

- `jQuery('<a id="id5" name="link"></a>');` will work
- `jQuery('<a id="id5" name="link" href=""></a>');` will **not** work.

Is there any know issue or workaround for this problem?? Thanks in advice…

***EDIT:***

To clarify: I don't want to create an element using known attributes. I have a function that returns a ready HTML code. I want to use this code to extract the image tag and then get its attributes. I don't know if the returned HTML will be the same structure. I just know that it contains an image tag. Here is the code I used before:

```
jQuery(html).find('img:first').attr('class').match(/\image-(\d+)\b/)[1]
```

Comment: try this jQuery('body').append('<a href="#"  name="link">Link</a>');

Answer (score 24):

I would use different approach:

```
var newLink = $("<a />", {
    id : "id5",
    name : "link",
    href : "http://www.google.com/",
    text : "some text"
});
```

Comment: var a = document.createElement("a"); a.setAttribute("anything-you-want", "attr value"). - See more https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 7):

This should work (tested):

```
var thelink = $('<a>',{
    text: 'linktext',
    title: 'some title',
    href: 'somelink.html'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
$(a).attr('href','index.html').attr('id','xyz').addClass('example');
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further trial & error it turned out that this is an issue regarding Safari. In Chrome my code works great.

I finally got a fix. I just wrap the HTML string I'm getting back from the function into `<div>` tags:

```
html = "<div>" + html + "</div>";
```